# Include files in Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2 httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have a large httpd.conf file, most of which is virtual hosts. Is there a way to make a file, say virtual_hosts.conf, and include it from httpd.conf? I've googled a bit, but can't seem to find much as far as includes, just module loading.

Comment: Don't google for this.  Read the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).

Comment: @AndrewSchulman: You know I asked this question over 3 years ago... right?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Information on apache httpd.conf files can be found at [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include).

Some snippets have been copied from this website to ensure that the information is not lost if the link would deprecated:

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/ssl.conf
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

*Relative paths:*

```
Include conf/ssl.conf
Include conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

*Wildcards:*

```
Include conf/vhosts/*/*.conf
```

Comment: Note that "relative paths" are relative to the defined [`ServerRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot).

Answer (score 11):

I separate each virtual host into it's own vhost config file, that way you don't wind up searching through a giant document looking for one little directive. Similar to Quanta's post:

```
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/*.conf
```

Just place it as the last line in your httpd.conf

then just split your single vhosts.conf into individual files for each domain, i.e.

```
domain1.conf
domain2.conf
domain3.conf
etc....
```

much easier to manage.
-sean

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#include) directive:

```
Include /path/to/virtual_hosts.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

**IncludeOptional**

Also you can use [IncludeOptional](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional) directive

```
IncludeOptional conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

So in such case there can be no any appropriate file. Or as exactly said in documentation,

> It works identically to the Include directive, but it will be silently
>   ignored (instead of causing an error) if wildcards are used and they
>   do not match any file or directory or if a file path does not exist on
>   the file system.

**BUT!**

Pay attention that some versions of Apache really **fails to start** in cases when "file path does not exist on the file system". Like on example above if there is no directory `conf/vhosts/`.

So, in such a problem you may be restricted in fact in safe usage of this directive by non-using some subdirectories when you are not sure if they exists

Like such a manner:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot    "/var/www/example.com"
ServerName      "example.com"
ServerAlias     "www.example.com" "example.com" 
...

IncludeOptional /var/www/example.com/*.httpd.conf

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot    "/var/www/other.org"
ServerName      "other.org"
ServerAlias     "www.other.org" "other.org" 
...

IncludeOptional /var/www/other.org/*.httpd.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

When some like

```
IncludeOptional /var/www/other.org/*.httpd.conf
```

will **works good** (have you any file matching given mask or not), but

```
IncludeOptional /var/www/other.org/config_optional_subdir/*.conf
```

**will fail** if there is no such subdirectory `config_optional_subdir`.

Note that

```
IncludeOptional /var/www/other.org/extra.httpd.conf
```

**will fail** too if at least one of sites will not have **exactly** specified file `extra.httpd.conf`. Wildcards are the key.

---

So, if common site configuration **created and can be recreated automatically** by some **template**, but some concrete site requires an extra apache configuration that cant be wrote just in a .htaccess file - you can use this approach.